# Fast string formatting in for loop

Tags: javascript, optimization

I have a function that loops through large objects of raw data, translating coded strings into readable words. The function is very basic, and I keep wondering if I should use an object instead containing the words to be detected and translated. This would be cleaner-looking and more flexible, but it would not like it to harm the performance of the script, since it needs to run through potentially thousands of items.

```
function formatTitle(input) {
    var input_lowercase = input.toLowerCase() 
    if (input == "total") {
        return "Title"
    } else if ( input_lowercase == "type" || input_lowercase == "dokumenttype" ||  input_lowercase == "km_type"  ) {
        return label_documenttype
    } else if ( input_lowercase.indexOf("tema_") >= 0 || input_lowercase == "spesfikasjon" ) {
        return label_theme
    } else if ( input_lowercase.indexOf("prosess_") >= 0) {
        return label_process   
    } else if (input.indexOf("SM_") >= 0) {
        return input.substr(3);           
    } 
    else {
        return input.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input.slice(1)
    }
}
```

There are more exceptions in the list, I've shortened it a bit down for practical reasons. I use the function in the following context (when t_formatheader is switched on):

```
    if ( skipping_mechanism == "lookup" ) { //42% faster than switch block in IE
        for (var key in arr_firstnode) {                
            if (key in keysToIgnore) continue;  
            if ( t_formatheader == "1" ) {
                arrayPushUnknown( columns, formatTitle( key ), "", true, key )
            }
            else {
                arrayPushUnknown( columns, key, "", true, key )     
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Question, does the string in reality *start* with `tema_` and `prosess_` and `SML_` or could it really be anywhere ?

Comment: @konijn Good question! Yes, in this case the strings start with this, so I could do a check from the beginning of the string instead of the anywhere-searching "indexOf", I assume that this might increase performance a slight bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need a mix of lookup object(s) and regular if statements; there are clearly direct matches, matches on the prefix and the rest. Also, to write `else if` is pointless since you `return` anyway in previous `if` checks, so you can simply use

```
if(condition){
  return value
}
if(condition2){ // <- no else here
  return value2
}
```

All that together you could consider something like this:

```
var formatTitleDirectMapping = {
  'total' : 'title',
  'type' : label_documenttype,
  'dokumenttype' : label_documenttype,
  'km_type' : label_documenttype,
  'spesfikasjon' : label_theme,
}

var formatTitlePrefixMapping = {
  'tema_' : label_theme,
  'prosess_' : label_process,
  'dokumenttype' : label_documenttype,
  'km_type' : label_documenttype,
}    

function formatTitle(input) {
  var lower = input.toLowerCase();
  //Is there a straight forward conversion? Then get out
  if( formatTitleDirectMapping[lower] )
    return formatTitleDirectMapping[lower];
  //Is there a straight forward conversion for the prefix? Then get out
  var prefix = lower.split("_")[0];
  if( formatTitlePrefixMapping[prefix] )
    return formatTitlePrefixMapping[prefix];
  //Put the conversions that dont lend themselves to lookup structures here
  if( prefix == "sm") {
    return input.substr(3);           
  } 
  //Catch all
  return input.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input.slice(1)
}
```